# Tools for Web Development

Tags: web, web-deployment, frontend, backend, middleware

I'm working in a team of 4 on an academic course selection and registration site for our college. We're doing it as a project for one of the courses we're currently enrolled in, so we have around 4 months to complete it [including other academic workload].

The site would involve user logins, comments and reviews of individual courses, time table creation using user preferences and more on similar lines. If we're successful, we could even port this to other colleges.

I wanted to ask what would be the **ideal stack of web frameworks and languages** to use for this kind of a project. We're very well versed with python at the moment and have intermediate knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP and JQuery. Moreover, we **don't mind learning anything new** as long as it helps us create a better product - like I was looking at R on R and bootstrap.

So, can you tell us what to choose for frontend, backend, connecting the two etc?

Comment: I noticed this question got downvoted. I upvoted as actually, I don't think this is a "help us with our project" question, but a "what's best practice" question. Though I will contend that it could be construed a being vague and subjective, and we **hate** subjectivity here!

Comment: Way too vague and subjective. Anyone who does webdev can answer with their favorite stack.

Comment: @IanClark: How can I make the question more to the point? I'm new to webdev and am in the process of finding out new practices. I'm doing courses on CodeAcademy to get a hang of some of the languages. What more information can I provide you with to help you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Though in my opinion that's not a terrible thing. This question is just subjective by nature, but even if I end up fighting with Joe Bloggs about whether x is better than y, it might prove useful to you as you can go and explore them both and decide for yourself. I also understand why SO don't like these kinds of questions as **there is no answer**

Comment: Perhaps rather than "can you tell us what to choose" you could rephrase to "could you give me viable solutions", then the person who lists off all 1 million options can get the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK as commented on, this question is really subjective, so I'll try to remove any personal bias from my suggestions:

> I'm working in a team of 4

- Use version control software so that the development process is smooth. The most popular one is Git, but Subversion is very simple too. I've not tried Mercurial but that's a third option

> We're very well versed with python at the moment

- OK cool. [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a very popular Python-based web framework. I've not used it myself, but I've heard that the docs are really good, and the good knowledge of Python should help. I think Databasing and logins etc. is pretty routine with Django. Alternatively you could use PHP and [Drupal](https://drupal.org/). I know there's a lot of "which is best" surrounding those two options, but I won't make any input, other than if you know Python, Django seems like a good fit.

> What would be the ideal stack of web frameworks

- Pfft... too vague to comment really. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is immensely popular, and in my opinion that's because it's very good, but there are literally hundreds of frameworks you could use. You could look at [Initializr and HTML5BoilerPlate](http://www.initializr.com/) too which seem like pretty good foundations on which to build a site. I know they include build scripts which could be really useful.

I could go on, but I'm that's enough to get you started.

Comment: So I looked around a bit more and also talked to some of my seniors (one of whom built this last summer: [link]http://www.usebackpack.com/). 
What I've made out of it is that Ruby is something that is going to help me inevitably in the future - so might as well grab this opportunity to learn it. The final stack I've decided to take up is: RoR for server side scripting, JQuery for client side, Bootstrap for frontend and MySQL for the backend. 
I know its arcing towards being subjective again, but do I need to worry about any performance or compatibility issues with this configuration?

Comment: In general I'd say it's incredibly rare you'll ever need to worry about performance issues with mainstream languages if used correctly. With databasing it's much more important but not until you really throw a tonne of data at it. Compatibility wise, jQuery <2 supports IE > 7, which you may need to take into account, and Bootstrap only supports IE > 8 - but in general just be aware of these things as and when you come to use them.